# FT5406 touchscreen sends events but input does not work

Tags: pi-3, touchscreen

I have a Raspi 3B with the official 7" touchscreen attached. The screen works (showed the under-voltage sign when attaching only the screen controller to a 2.1 A power supply, so I'm connecting the Raspi to its own supply for now) but the touch controls don't.

It seems to be recognized fine:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dmesg | grep -i FT5406
[    3.593291] rpi-ft5406 rpi_ft5406: Probing device
[    3.593960] input: FT5406 memory based driver as /devices/virtual/input/input0
```

And when I run `evtest`:

```
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:      FT5406 memory based driver
Select the device event number [0-0]: 0
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x0 vendor 0x0 product 0x0 version 0x0
Input device name: "FT5406 memory based driver"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 330 (BTN_TOUCH)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 0 (ABS_X)
      Value    305
      Min        0
      Max      800
    Event code 1 (ABS_Y)
      Value    208
      Min        0
      Max      480
    Event code 47 (ABS_MT_SLOT)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max        9
    Event code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max      800
    Event code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max      480
    Event code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max    65535
Properties:
  Property type 1 (INPUT_PROP_DIRECT)
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
```

Then when I touch the screen, I get event data:

```
Event: time 1496960092.603213, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 306
Event: time 1496960092.603213, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 256
Event: time 1496960092.603213, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 306
Event: time 1496960092.603213, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 256
```

So it looks like the hardware and drivers work just fine, but I still can't control the cursor or click on anything. Do I have to configure X to actually use the input somewhere? Could it be because I also have a Bluetooth keyboard with touchpad set up?